# Ansible prompt_vars error: GetPassWarning: Cannot control echo on the terminal

Tags: python, docker, ansible

I am using Ansible and Docker for automating the environment build process. I use prompt_vars to try to collect the username and password for the git repo but unfortunately i got this error:

> GetPassWarning: Cannot control echo on the terminal

The docker ubuntu version is 14.04 and python version is 2.7

Answer (score 0):

The error

> GetPassWarning: Cannot control echo on the terminal

is raised by Python and indicates that the terminal you are using does not provide `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. In this case its `stderr`.

As there is not much information provided in the question I guess it is tried to use interactive elements like `prompt_vars` inside a `Dockerfile` which is IMHO not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I am using Ansible prompt_vars inside Docker container.